# Pythonic way of looping through a list/dict of regex patterns and extracting string

Tags: python, r, regex, loops

As someone who has written everything in R for years, I'm still unsure if I'm handling iteration/list comprehensions the best way in python. As an example, let's say I have the string:

```
string = "Imported as of 1 Jan 2020"
```

And I want to build a date object from the string, where my patterns are stored to a `named list` in R, or `dict` in python as follows:

```
dates_r =  list(
    day = '[0-9]{1,2}(?=\\s+)',
    month = '(\\w+)(?=(\\s)[0-9]{4})',
    year = '[0-9]{4}$'
)

dates_py = {
    'day':r'[0-9]{1,2}(?=\s+)',
    'month':r'(\w+)(?=(\s)[0-9]{4})',
    'year':r'[0-9]{4}$'
}
```

**In R I can simply**:

```
> dates_out_r <- mapply(stringi::stri_extract_all_regex, pattern = dates_r, str = string, simplify = F)
> dates_out_r 
$day
[1] "1"

$month
[1] "Jan"

$year
[1] "2020"
```

**Is there a better way than what I am currently doing in python?**

```
dates_py = {
    'day': r'[0-9]{1,2}(?=\s+)',
    'month': r'(\w+)(?=(\s)[0-9]{4})',
    'year': r'[0-9]{4}$'
}

dates_out = {}

for key, value in dates_py.items():
    rgx = re.compile(value)
    dates_out[key] = re.search(rgx, date_str)[0]
dates_out
{'day': '1', 'month': 'February', 'year': '2020'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use dict comprehension
its essetially the same as `for` loop, but shorter

```
d = {k: re.search(regex, string)[0] for k, regex in dates_py.items()}
```

there is also kind of equivalent of mapply, but looks pretty ugly (at least in my implementation)

```
dict(map(lambda k, regex: (k, re.search(regex, string)[0]), dates_py.keys(), dates_py.values()))
```

also note, that case `re.search(...) is None` isnt handled, handling will add event more code, which is not cool for one-liner